# PickerView layout - background too big

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView which is the right size, except I want to background to be a lot smaller, so that the spinning part is bigger within the frame of the picker view.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I get your question right, but there is no way to customize the `UIPickerView` controller. The only thing you can do is to overlay the `UIPickerView` with a custom image like it is shown at [Custom background color of UIDatePicker and UIPickerView](http://www.jademind.com/blog/posts/uidatepicker-and-uipickerview). There they simply created an image with transparent parts and put it on top of the control.

Comment: Yea, I did that to partly cover it, but if I cover all the background to the edge of the spinning part, it makes the whole thing seem small, and UIPickerView has a maximum size, so to make it bigger I was hoping to increase the size of the spinner within the frame of the picker.